# cant use function int the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

the function GameController($scope) doesn't work and I don't know why, can someone help please?

```
 (function () {
  angular.module('MemoryGame').controller('GameController', GameController);

  GameController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  console.log("hhhhhhh");


  function GameController($scope) {
    console.log("gggggg");

    var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".all-cards");
    var i = 0;
    var textArray = []; // array that saving the text of the car
    var count = 0; // count the card flipped
    var save_cards = [];



    cards.forEach((card) => {
      card.addEventListener('click', function () {


      });
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting. That will help to identify the problem.

Comment: Posting the relevant HTML would also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are getting - but try setting up your controller a little differently. You can inject $scope object at the same time you declare your controller.

```
var app = angular.module('MemoryGame', []);

app.controller('GameController', function($scope) {

    var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".all-cards");
    var i = 0;
    var textArray = []; // array that saving the text of the car
    var count = 0; // count the card flipped
    var save_cards = [];

    cards.forEach((card) => {
      card.addEventListener('click', function () {
    });
});
```

Also, did you declare your ng-app and ng-controller correctly in your HTML?

```
<body ng-app="MemoryGame">
    <div ng-controller="GameController">
        {{hello}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should share any error messages and some html, too